Appwrite- Api error exception doesn't make sense. Randomly stopped working
AppwriteException: Invalid password param: Password must be between 8 and 256 characters long.
Front end code:
  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading((loading) => !loading);
    setResult('');
    
    try {
      //await login(email, password)
      //const response = await axios.post('/api/login', {email, password} ) // Send as query paramers );
      await loginappwrite(email, password1);  //await account.createEmailPasswordSession( email,password1)
      //login(response)
      setIsloggedin(()=> true)
      router.replace('/dashboard')
    } catch (error: any) {
      alert(error);
     // alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data.detail));//
    }
    finally{
      setLoading((loading) => !loading);
    }
  }

Back end code:
const UserContext = createContext();
  
export function UserProvider(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null);
  

  async function loginappwrite(email, password) {
    //const loggedIn = await axios.post('/api/login', {email, password} )
  
    const session_details= await account.createEmailPasswordSession(email , password);
   // await axios.post('/api/test', {session_details} )
  /*
    setSession(session_details);
    sessionStorage.setItem('session', session)
    const loggedIn = await account.get()
    setUser(loggedIn);
    */
    //sessionStorage.setItem('user', user)
  }
    

Was just working. Doesn't make sense for a login api call. I think appwrite is to blame. Don't see how it could be working this morning and now be sending me an error message on password creation?? ..for a login.
Any help appreciated.
